# Populate current date and time as default in footer template

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I populate the RadDateTimePicker with a default of Now below:

```
<FooterTemplate>
    <telerik:RadDateTimePicker Width="150px" ID="txt_QualityInspectorDateTimeFooter" runat="server" /> 
</FooterTemplate>
```

Comment: show some code what you tried

Comment: <FooterTemplate>
                                    <telerik:RadDateTimePicker Width="150px" ID="txt_QualityInspectorDateTimeFooter" runat="server">
                                    </telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
                                </FooterTemplate>

Comment: #Ganesh_Devlekar """""""this is the code for datetime picker and I want to set current Datetime as default"""""" how is it possible ??

Comment: What do u mean, Mr Aydiin Adn?

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/forums/raddatepicker-display-default-date

Answer (score 0):

Check this link :
[DateTimePicker](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/editors-datetimepicker-basics-raddatetimepicker-properties.html)

```
txt_QualityInspectorDateTimeFooter.radDateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found correct solution:

```
GridViewRow gridStoppageFooterRow = gvw_InspectionMainProcess.FooterRow;
RadDateTimePicker txt_LineInchargeDateTime = gridStoppageFooterRow.FindControl("txt_LineInchargeDateTimeFooter") as RadDateTimePicker;
txt_LineInchargeDateTime.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
```